# How to remove a Branch Policies inside All repositories Policies settings

Tags: azure-repos

I add new branch policy inside Azure Repos > Project Settings > All Repositories > Repositories > Policies, settings.
I enter a pattern and define few options.

Now I want to remove/delete that branch policy, but I do not find any way to remove it (even If I disable all options).

Answer (score 2):

Go to Azure Repos > Project Settings > All Repositories > Repositories > Policies. Scroll down to Branch policies. Select one and click on it. It opens Cross-Repository policies.. Scroll down, select rule to delete, in the right click on 3 dots and from menu select Delete.

[Cross repository policies - Delete one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn2eX.png)